# Load a value of a jquery field

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I will try to clarify my question a little more as I can. I get the data in json format as they present themselves and I would like that by selecting a quantity on a line, it filled me the value of the corresponding price on the corresponding line.
Normally are retrieved in php from a database and it works locally, anytime when I select a quantity from the first line it fills me with the right value. But when I select a quantity from the second row, it changes the value of the first row instead of filling me with the price of the second row.

```js
 $("form").on('change', '.qty', function(){

   var qty = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
    url: data,
    data: {'qty':qty},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data){
     if(data ==''){       
      $('.price').val(0);
     }else{
    $.each(data, function(index, element){
     $('.price').val(element.price);
    });       
      }
    }
   });
});
```

```html
<form>
 <table id="fact-tablee" style="margin-top:10px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
                                          
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>                                             
</tr>
                                        
<tr class="tr">
    <td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td> 
 <td><select name="qty[]" class="qty">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="" class="price"></td>
</tr> 
<tr class="tr">
    <td><input type="text" name="item[]" value=""></td> 
 <td><select name="qty[]" class="qty">
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
 </select></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="price[]" value="" class="price"></td>
</tr>
                                    
  </table>
</form>
```

```
[
  {id:"1", item:"Coca", qty:"12", price:"250"},
  {id:"2", item:"Orange", qty:"20", price: "102"},
  {id:"3", item:"pepsi", qty: "30", price: "250"}
 ]
```

Comment: You fetching your data correctly right in JSON format? You just need to populate your data into price field?

Comment: Kindly provide the JSON that's supposed to be returned after the ajax call.

Comment: @SimpleDev Nekro, this question is a little bit confusing. And also, your snippet code is returning an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
Can you clarify everything for us to help you ?
Maybe creating a JsFiddle example?

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid Thanks Zaid bin Khalid, that's exactly my problem. I get the data in json format and I would like that by selecting a quantity on a line, it filled me the value of the corresponding price on the corresponding line.

Comment: @SimpleDevNekro you very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the ajax call is returning, but if I understand the question correctly and you are getting the data in the format shown in the question, then you can obtain the price using -

```
 var qty = $(this).val();
 var data = [{
         id: "1",
         item: "Coca",
         qty: "12",
         price: "250"
     },
     {
         id: "2",
         item: "Orange",
         qty: "20",
         price: "102"
     },
     {
         id: "3",
         item: "pepsi",
         qty: "30",
         price: "250"
     }
 ];

 var price = data.find(x => x.qty === qty).price;
```